# asp.net.MVC How to produce RESTful url like this: /mycontroller/myaction/24

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Could someone show me the syntax of an Html.ActionLink that will produce a hyperlink that looks like this:

```
<a h ref="/mycontroller/myaction/67">mylinktext</a>
```

thanks.
Terrence

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends more on how you set up your routes. But if you only have the default route and `myaction` takes one parameter named id it can look like this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("mylinktext", "myaction", "mycontroller", new { id = 67 }, null) %>
```

Or, if you want and have mvc features or mvc2, it can look like this:

```
<%=Html.ActionLink<mycontroller>(x => x.myaction(67), "mylinktext")%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Mattias.

Answer (score 1):

To generate a link, use the HtmlHelper and the Action extension...

```
<%= Html.ActionLink ("mycontroller", "myaction", new { id = 67 }) %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Kieron.